# Using geom_tile for heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I've been working on a problem for two full days and cannot seem to get it right. I want to create a plot that shows classroom usage at my college for each hour of the day and each day of the week so it would be easy for our instructional managers to see what classrooms are being underutilized.

The data I have to work with looks something like this:

```
room strTime endTime days pctFill
1101 1345    1500    MW   91.67
1102 1345    1630    MW   95.83
1102 1730    2015    MW   66.67
1104 0915    1200    MW   62.50
1104 1345    1630    MW   45.83
```

Each line in the df represents a single class that meets in a single room. "room" is the room number. "strTime" and "endTime" is the starting and ending time for a class in that room. These are text fields but could be easily converted to times or any other format. "days" is the days of the week that the class meets. I know that I'll have to divide the "days" data and believe that it's easiest to create a new row for each day, so the first row would be divided into two rows: one for Monday and one for Wednesday. "pctFill" is the percent of fill for that room (a room with a capacity of 20 students but contains 15 students would be 75.00 pctFill).

I would like to create a heatmap-type of plot using geom_tile (or geom_raster or geom_rect). I envision the plot would have the days of the week along the x-axis and the times of the day along the y-axis where each intersecting block would be filled with a color that represents the percent of classroom fill. I've completed several tutorials and understand the concept of geom_tile and can create a heck-of-a-plot for mtcars. Unfortunately, the data that I'm using doesn't seem to work the same way since it's time rather than a simple categorical variable, I think. I've tried to create a plot using all three geoms but without much success. I can get geom_tile to almost work, but each tile is centered on the start time rather than the lower edge of the box on the start time. Also, the boxes are all the same height, which is likely due to the y-axis scale. I tried using geom_raster and creating a grid with the y-axis divided into 15-minute intervals and then filling in each grid block with an appropriate color. Unfortunately, whatever I was doing wrong with that plot yielded only an empty grid. The geom_rect would have worked but I could not figure out a way to make the rectangles wide without creating a pseudo-variable with a value between each of the room values.

Here is my closest approach to something that works:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_tile(
    data = df
    ,mapping = aes(x = room
                   ,y = strTime
                   ,fill = pctFill
                   )
    ,color = 'white'
    ,alpha = 0.5
    ) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'steelblue')
```

If anyone has a sample plot similar to what I'm doing and would not mind sharing the code for that plot I would deeply appreciate it. Or, just a pointer in the right direction may be enough. Thanks for any help you can offer.

[image: Best geom_tile effort]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

First, your sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)
txt <- 'room strTime endTime days pctFill
1101 1345    1500    MW   91.67
1102 1345    1630    MW   95.83
1102 1730    2015    MW   66.67
1104 0915    1200    MW   62.50
1104 1345    1630    MW   45.83'

df <- read.table(text = txt, header = T)
```

Then, we transform the data such that each day of the week is in its own row:

```
df <- read.table(text = txt, header = T) %>% 
  mutate(days = str_split(days, '')) %>% 
  unnest(days)

   room strTime endTime pctFill days
1  1101    1345    1500   91.67    M
2  1101    1345    1500   91.67    W
3  1102    1345    1630   95.83    M
4  1102    1345    1630   95.83    W
5  1102    1730    2015   66.67    M
6  1102    1730    2015   66.67    W
7  1104     915    1200   62.50    M
8  1104     915    1200   62.50    W
9  1104    1345    1630   45.83    M
10 1104    1345    1630   45.83    W
```

And finally, a plot using `geom_rect()`:

```
plot.rooms <- ggplot(data = df, aes(xmin = room - 0.33, xmax = room + 0.33,  ymin = strTime, ymax = endTime)) +
  geom_rect(aes(alpha = pctFill)) +
  facet_grid(facets = ~days) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = sort(unique(df$room))) +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.3, 1))
print(plot.rooms)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty embarrassed -- this is such a simple solution. I can't believe that I worked on this for a full two days and didn't find this solution myself. The key seems to be in getting the input data properly formatted but I was worried about how to set up ggplot! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Data input and cleaning is 90% of the job, in most cases.